# $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(g(1 + t, 2), h(1 + t, 2)) - f(g(1, 2), h(1, 2)) }{t} ?$

Tags: limits, partial-derivative

**Q:** Suppose that the functions $f : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ are
continuously differentiable. Express the following two limits in terms of partial derivatives of these functions:

**a.** $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(g(1 + t, 2), h(1 + t, 2)) - f(g(1, 2), h(1, 2)) }{t}$

**b.** $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(g(1, 2) + t, h(1, 2)) - f(g(1, 2), h(1, 2))}{t}$

**A:**  **a.** $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g} (g(1,2)) \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} ((1,2)) + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial h} (h(1,2)) \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x} ((1,2)) \ ??$

**b.** $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g} (g(1,2)) \ ??$

Did I get the answers right?

Answer (score 2):

a)

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g} (g(1,2),h(1,2)) \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} ((1,2)) + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial h} (g(1,2),h(1,2)) \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x} ((1,2)) \ $$

b)

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (g(1,2),h(1,2)) $$

Comment: Why the second one is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and not $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g}$?

Comment: @Edi Okay. Let us denote the numbers $g(1,2)$ and $h(1,2)$ respectively by $a$ and $b$. What is the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+t,b)-f(a,b)}{t}$ ? It is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (a,b)$.